# Power loss in a capacitor vs inductor

Tags: capacitor, inductor, coil, energy

Is there are a general rule of thumb if one of these stores energy more efficiently than the other?

When properties are approximateily comparable, are energy losses bigger with a coil or with a capacitor?

Comment: At what rate of usage? Any other considerations: size, cost, etc.?

Comment: For how long do you need to store the energy? Capacitors exists with extremely little parasitic self-drain despite (near) full voltage across them so depending on capacitor type its seconds to months whereas inductors will have series resistance so freewheeling the current will deplete them rather quickly, in the ms to s range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *When properties are ~comparable, are energy loses bigger with a coil
> or with a capacitor?*

For the same occupancy / volume, a capacitor is a much more efficient energy storage component compared to an inductor. By an order of two magnitudes roughly. Also, for the same occupancy / volume, a capacitor can store more energy than an inductor.

But, you could also factor in the method of putting energy into the capacitor or inductor. For instance, if you charged a capacitor from a voltage source, you would immediately lose 50% of the energy (a pulse of "infinite" current would also flow theoretically). On the other hand, if you chose to store energy in an inductor from a voltage source, then you would do so much more efficiently.

But, if you store energy in a capacitor from a ramping voltage source (for instance a constant current source), the energy lost is near-enough zero. And, if you tried to store energy in an inductor using a current source, you would lose half the energy (and be faced with a massive voltage spike).

For minimizing ongoing energy losses (once it is stored) you would always choose a capacitor.

Comment: And a battery is even better, if the goal is energy storage. And a tank of gasoline is even better than a battery, at energy storage.

Comment: A tank of gasoline has a massive energy storage per unit volume but, to make that energy do decent work means high conversion losses i.e. internal combustion feeding a generator. And, neither battery nor gasoline compare with the instantaneous energy levels you can liberate from a capacitor (or even an inductor).